# Placing text block based on the middle of its bottom edge

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm placing some text at arbitrary absolute positions inside a wrapper-`div` on my page. The most natural placement would be to specify the `left` and `top` values of the middle of the bottom edge of the element boxes of the text I am placing. My current solution seems complicated with 3 nested `div`s. Is there an easier way?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="c">TEXT123<br/>TEXT123123</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a">↖</div> <!--for illustration only-->
</div>
```

with

```
.wrapper {width:300px; height:200px; background-color:yellow;}
.a {position:absolute; left:200px; top:100px;}
.b {position:absolute; bottom:0;}
.c {position:relative; left:-50%; border:solid 1px;}
```

[image]

See: http://jsfiddle.net/TTc23/

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you :

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="c">TEXT123<br/>TEXT123123</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {width:300px;height:200px;background-color:yellow;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center}
.c {border:solid 1px;margin:auto; width:100px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zHEXQ/

- I have added following additional css properties to "wrapper" div

  display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center
- changed css for "c" div to :

  .c {border:solid 1px;margin:auto; width:100px}
- removed divs "a" & "b"

Comment: Please don't change the wrapper div because other elements rely on it. Also, how do I specify the position of the box (`left:200px; top:100px;`) with your solution?

Comment: I thought the problem was centering the div containing the text. If that is not so, then, sorry, my solution may not be the one.  You can remove margin:auto and specify margin-top & margin-left value to achieve the placement you need.